# Use QThreadPool inside a worker task

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11

I have QThreadPool which run some tasks.
I need also create new tasks in other tasks.
To do that i think implement something like following:

```
class Task : public QRunnable
{
    QThreadPool *pool;
public:
    Task (QThreadPool *p) : pool(p){}

    void run()
    {
        static std::atomic<int> counter = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
        qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();

        int c;
        if ((c = counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) < 10) {
            pool->start(new Task(pool));
            counter.store(c + 1, std::memory_order_release);
        }

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...

    QThreadPool threadPool;
    threadPool.start(new Task(&threadPool));

    //...
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is the right approach.

Comment: The general approach looks fine, but the seperate `load`/`store` of counter is unsafe (as it could be changed in between the calls). However, if you only use it to control the number of parallel task, you don't even need it. [`QThreadPool::setMaxThreadCount`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#maxThreadCount-prop) should be used to control this instead.

Comment: @Felix OK, thank you